# Create a bmp of a string using a TTF file using C?

Tags: c, truetype

I have a new project assigned to me today. I need to load a TTF file and then write the specified string to a bitmap using that font. However, I do not have much information about the TTF structure. Is there any library specifically for this job?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a look at the [SDL_ttf](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/index.html) project. SDL is also a good start to build a small gfx app.

[Here](http://wiki.gamedev.net/index.php/SDL_ttf:Tutorials:Fonts_in_OpenGL) is also a useful tutorial aboud using SDL_ttf in OpenGL and rendering text as textures.

Comment: well, the thing is I cannot use opengl orany big library bec I have limited resources